# Handy way to plot surface spherical harmonics?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spherical-coordinate

Does anyone know of a good and simple way to do it?

An online tool or a Python script would be great.

So far, the best I have found is:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268830/drawing-spherical-harmonic-density-plots-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere-in-tikz-pgfp

However, I could not install `mpl_toolkits.basemap` and then the nice script is halted.

Comment: I also found [this page](http://www.magben.de/?h1=mathematik_fuer_ingenieure_mit_python&h2=kugelflaechenfunktionen) which plots some nice spherical harmonics.

Comment: you can manage to install mpl_toolkits.basemap, put the problem in the question.

Comment: I finally found a neat way to it here: http://keatonb.github.io/archivers/shanimate